Another way to copy an Excel cell range in email body?
I have an issue while copying a range from Excel to email body.
I already have a pretty much working script.
My issue is that the tool is crashing due to building too many temp_documents. I had the idea of coping the range directly in the email body, that also didn't work.
I need a better way to copy the data in the email_body. Can you please give me some other way/ways to copy an excel Range in mail_body?

This is the format of the data.
The function that I use is RangeToHTML(rngHtmlBody)
Private Function RangeToHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim Fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
    Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = Fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangeToHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangeToHTML = Replace(RangeToHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
    Kill TempFile
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set Fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function


How about reducing the number of temp documents?

Try using Kill on TempWB as well.

@SolarMike i need to send over 200 mails and each mail has diffend information. So i need to build for every mail a new temp doc to copy the data in the email body.

So do 5 at a time... still can use a template for each one, just takes thinking about a different approach.

@SolarMike i found a way to get it to work. i added an DoEvents to the code. now it takes a bit longer, but it runs beautiful. It turns out It was  not the temp Excel documents that i was not closing but the VBA instances that were created with every temp doc.. Thank you for your help and input, it helped me fix the problem.

You can use a small email-sending freeware like BLAT through VBA.
You can tell BLAT to use an HTML file you generate through your VBA as your email body, and then send the email. Never had an issue with that tool !
Open "c:\Temp\MailHeader.txt" For Output As #2
Print #2, Me.Subject
Close #2

Open "c:\Temp\MailBody.txt" For Output As #2
Print #2, Me.BodyText
Close #2

sBlatCommandLine = BLAT_PATH & " -to """ & sListOfEmails & """  -f ""noreply@mydomain.com""  -server webappserv.mydomain.com -html  -sf c:\Temp\MailHeader.txt  -bodyF c:\Temp\MailBody.txt "

Shell sBlatCommandLine

